# Printing no output to a text file in python while reading specific lines

Tags: python, loops, text-files

I want to print every third line (starting from line 2) from a file to a new file.
The example of the file (`line.txt`) is

```
line1
line2
line3
line4
line5
line6
line7
line8
line9
line10
line11
```

The output will be

```
line2
line5
line8
line11
```

The script that I have written is

```
with open ('line.txt') as file:
    for line in file.read().split("\n")[1::3]:
        print (line)
        f = open('output.txt','w')
        f.write(line)
        f.close()
```

But nothing is being copied in the `output.txt file`. The`output.txt` remains blank. Even if I `print` the `line` after running the script in python IDLE, the `line` returns blank ' '. But during running the script, the output is the desired output i.e.

```
line2
line5
line8
line11
```

Any help or tips would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `f = open('output.txt','w')` should be outside your loop.

Comment: So is `f.close`, or better yet, use `with open`

Comment: Thanks a lot.....It was great help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are closing the output.txt file and opening it again every time in your loop. I would suggest to put these out of the loop:

```
with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
    with open ('line.txt', 'r') as file:
        for line in file.readlines()[1::3]:
            print(line)
            f.write(line)
```

note: I also added `+'\n` to the write statement to include line endings in your output.txt

Edit: as @DeepSpace rightly noted you could better use `with open()` for both files and `readlines()` instead of `read().split('\n')`. Using `with open()` you don't need to remember to close it.

Comment: Some nitpicking: 1. If you are using `with` to open one file, why not use it for the other? it can even be done in the same indentation level. 2. Instead of `file.read().split("\n")` I'd just use `file.readlines()`

Comment: @DeepSpace: thanks, I added your improvements to the answer

Answer (score 0):

```
with open ('line.txt') as file:
        f = open('output.txt','w')
        for line in file.read().split("\n")[1::3]:
            outputline=line
            f.write(outputline)
        f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

the following script write in an file `output.txt` according your description ***I wish to print every third line (starting from line 2) from a file to a new file***

```
output_file = open("output.txt", "a")
with open ('line.txt') as file:
    for line in file.readlines()[1::3]:
        output_file.write(line)
output_file.close()
```

I am using `readlines()` instead of `read()` becaute it reads a whole line instead of read a single string. Also I am using open file with `"a"` instead of `"w"` because the Appending mode allows you to append content in the file. With `"w"` you were overwriting each iteration of the loop. I hope it helps.